# How to handle bad strings as pseudo booleans in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, gson

Let's say I'm using gson to serialize and deserialize json to and from a Kotlin data class. One of the values is a string set as "yes" or "no" and the other is a string set as "on" or "off". Yes, this is terrible terrible practice, but let's presume it can't be changed.

Whats the best way to handle this in Kotlin?

*APIdata.json*

```
{
   "value" : "On",
   "anotherValue" : "Yes"
}
```

*APIdata.kt*

```
data class APIdata (val value : String, val anotherValue: String)
```

I want to be able to treat them both as Booleans for the purposes of getting and setting.

Comment: Register an adapter in GSON so that you properly map it to a boolean field.

Comment: But how do you go back then? So, it works when deserializing to check `if("yes" || "on") return true` but what about serializing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mapping function and a corresponding constructor, also you can define get methods:

```
data class APIdata(val value: String, val anotherValue: String) {
    fun mapToBoolean(string: String) =
        when (string.toLowerCase()) {
            "yes" -> true
            "on"  -> true
            else  -> false
        }

    constructor(value: Boolean, anotherValue: Boolean) :
        this(if (value) "on" else "off", if (anotherValue) "yes" else "no")

    fun getValue(): Boolean {
        return mapToBoolean(value)
    }


    fun getAnotherValue(): Boolean {
        return mapToBoolean(anotherValue)
    }
}
```

In this case using a `data class` can be misleading, because the Kotlin compiler generates `hashCode` and `equals` assuming `value`and `anotherValue` are `String` rather than `Boolean`. It is better design to implement them yourself like this:

```
class APIdata( val value: String, private val anotherValue: String) {
    fun mapToBoolean(string: String) =
        when (string.toLowerCase()) {
            "yes" -> true
            "on"  -> true
            else  -> false
        }

    constructor(value: Boolean, anotherValue: Boolean) :
        this(if (value) "on" else "off", if (anotherValue) "yes" else "no")

    fun getValue(): Boolean {
        return mapToBoolean(value)
    }


    fun getAnotherValue(): Boolean {
        return mapToBoolean(anotherValue)
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as APIdata

        if (getValue() != other.getValue()) return false
        if (getAnotherValue() != other.getAnotherValue()) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = getValue().hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + getAnotherValue().hashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write that 'equals' much more succinctly if you just treat it as a boolean expression instead of trying to bail out early:  
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = this === other || (other is APIdata && getValue()==other.getValue() && getAnotherValue() == other.getAnotherValue())

Comment: Likewise, that hashCode function can be:  
   override fun hashCode() = Objects.hash(getValue(), getAnotherValue()).

Comment: The given implementation of equals and hashCode is what Intellij Idea or Android Studio generated for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [TypeAdapter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html).

```
class ApiDataTypeAdapter: TypeAdapter<APIData>() {

  override fun read(`in`: JsonReader) {
    var valOne = false
    var valTwo = false

    `in`.beginObject()
    while (`in`.hasNext()) {
        when(`in`.nextName()) {
          "val" -> valOne = `in`.nextString() == "On"
          "anotherVal" -> valTwo = `in`.nextString() == "Yes"
    }
    `in`.endObject()

    return APIData(valOne, valTwo)
  }

  override fun write(out: JsonWriter, apiData: APIData)
  {
    out.beginObject()
    out.name("val").value(if (apiData.`val`) "On" else "Off")
    out.name("anotherVal").value(if (apiData.anotherVal) "Yes" else "No")
    out.endObject()
  }
}
```

And then register it for your APIData class:

```
val builder = GsonBuilder()
builder.registerTypeAdapter(APIData::class.java, ApiDataTypeAdapter().nullSafe())
val gson = builder.create()
```